# webmatrix login information starter site (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, security, webmatrix

I just created a new Starter site on webmatrix using ASP.net, with the built in template.

I am wondering where the site stores all the password information? I understand WebSecurity is a built-in model, but I want to know where all these object information are being stored. The only columns in the user database table are "email" and "id".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have tables named 'webpages_...'? I think webpages_Membership is the one you are looking for.

Comment: No, i don't actually. Which is what I was confused about, because it does seem to save it somewhere, I can log in fine, and the site prompts default error messages. I went through the design document for the Starter Site template, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That's really weird. According to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership) they just should be there. I must be missing something here...

Answer (score 0):

@cesarse is correct about the table webPages_Membership.  Take a look in your web.config file and look for the connection string, which will let you know which database your data is being saved in.